# Eclipselink : any way to ignore certain missing nodes when unmarshalling XML?

Tags: eclipselink

I've got the below XML file, mapping file and POJO. The scenario is that the XML file may or may not contain the `id` element `<id>PartnerId</id>`. However, if it exists then I'd like to to be mapped to the POJO. Otherwise, it should just be ignored.

How do I achieve that? As it is right now, I keep getting exceptions telling me that

> "XPath must either contain an @ symbol for attributes or end in /text()
>   for text nodes. For example: "@name" or "name/text()"

As you can tell from the mapping file, I've tried to add `required="false"` and `default="0"`, but with no success.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partner>
    <key>partnerKey</key>
    <name>partnerName</name>
</partner>
```

**Mapping:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3"
    package-name="com.company.pas.entity">

    <java-types>
        <java-type name="com.company.pas.entity.Partner">
            <xml-root-element/>
            <xml-type prop-order="id key name"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="id" xml-path="id/text()" required="false" default="0"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="key" xml-path="key/text() "/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="name" xml-path="name/text()"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>

</xml-bindings>
```

POJO

```
package com.company.pas.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Partner {

    private int id;
    private String key;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @XmlElement(nillable=false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out by using the `<xml-transient />` element. This declares the element, but ignores it.